# useSelector conflict between application and npm package

Tags: redux, react-redux

**Issue Description:**

I have a React component within my application where I use `useSelector` to fetch data from the application's Redux store. In the same application, I also incorporate an npm package. I pass my aforementioned component to this npm package. The issue I'm encountering is that the `useSelector` within my component is now returning data from the Redux store of the npm package instead of the application's Redux store. It's worth noting that I have separate Redux providers for both the application and the npm package.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Set up a React application with its own Redux store.
2. Create a component within the application that uses `useSelector` to access data from the application's Redux store.
3. Integrate an npm package into the application, passing the above component to it.
4. Observe that the `useSelector` within the component is unexpectedly fetching data from the npm package's Redux store instead of the application's Redux store.

**Expected Behavior:**

The `useSelector` within the component should consistently retrieve data from the application's Redux store, irrespective of the presence of the npm package and its Redux store.

**Actual Behavior:**

The `useSelector` within the component is fetching data from the npm package's Redux store, which is not the expected behavior.

**Additional Information:**

- I have verified that separate Redux providers are correctly set up for both the application and the npm package.
- The npm package being used does not intentionally interfere with the application's Redux store.
- This issue disrupts the expected functionality of my application, as data from the wrong Redux store is being accessed within the component.

**Note:**

- I've isolated the same component and conducted tests, and it indeed functions correctly.